# How to set different values from other component in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

I am using a modal component from tailwindui. When using the vue code provided in a vue file (Modal.vue) and import this file in my base vue component (Home.vue) it works just fine. The modal will show up instantly which is fine. The example of the modal component is like this:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { Dialog, DialogPanel, DialogTitle, TransitionChild, TransitionRoot } from '@headlessui/vue'
import { CheckIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/outline'

const open = ref(true)
</script>
```

When setting true to false, the modal is not being shown as expected. But how can i set open to true when i have included my modal in my Home.vue component like this:

```
<template>
    <Modal/>
</template>

<script>

import Modal from '../Shared/Modal/Post';

export default {
    components: {
        Modal
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html).

Comment: Okay, will dive into it.  I guess the ref(true) they use is an example?

Answer (score 0):

As @Etheryte said you can use props.

Your home.vue

```
<template>
    <Modal :isShow="true" />
</template>

<script>

import Modal from '../Shared/Modal/Post';

export default {
    components: {
        Modal
    },
}
</script>
```

and your Modal.vue

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script>



export default {
    props: {
        isShow : {
           type: Boolean,
           default: false
        },
}
</script>
```